# What do you call an environment with specific species occuring together?

Tags: trees, forests

Different kinds of forests exist where I live. My favorite kind is composed predominantly of hemlock, striped maple, and silver birch. I've noticed these species often coexist in the same area. Other areas are dominated by red pine, or hardwoods, or beech and ironwood.

What do you call areas that are occupied with specific species that often occur in each others' company? Does hemlock-striped maple-silver birch have a specific name? I know taiga is a name for a certain kind of forest. That's what I'm after, but a level of classification more specific than biome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People seem to use the word **community** in various ways, for example biotic community, biological community and ecological community.

Among other resources, the [Pennsylvania National Heritage Program](https://www.naturalheritage.state.pa.us/naturalcommunities.aspx) states

> An **ecological community** is defined as a group of species that are commonly found together. Ecological communities may be animal or plant assemblages with similar habitat requirements and contain species which may influence each other or rely on similar processes in their environment. A community’s occurrence or presence is usually a result of underlying environmental conditions. For example, a particular group of plants adapted to extreme drought and high temperatures grow on shale barrens, while assemblages of plants and animals that are able to survive in periods of wet and dry live in vernal pool communities.

Comment: Botanist here. Bingo, that’s exactly the term for it. An individual community will generally just be referred to by its name or a short descriptor (“beech-maple forest”, “mixed oak savannah”, “greasewood playa”, etc.) but the unit being discussed is a community.